# Adding text color in beamer

Tags: beamer, color

I am trying to use `\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}` package given [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Using_colours_in_LaTeX) .I am using `\color{RubineRed}{NameName}` to change the color of the text `NameName`.But, the color of the text doesn't change.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|a|b|a|b|a|b|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{LightCyan}
  Name & Name&Name&NameName&NameName\\
  \hline
  \color{RubineRed}{NameName}&-&-&-&-\\
  NameName&NameName B &NameName B &- &NameName B\\
  NameName&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A\\
  NameName&NameName B &NameName &-&- \\
  NameName&NameName C&NameName C&NameName C&-\\
  NameName&-&NameName&-&-\\
  NameName&-&NameName&-&\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
} % end of scope of "\resizebox"  directive
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Please not that color only has one argument, either `{\color{RubineRed} NameName}` or `\textcolor{RubineRed}{NameName}`

Comment: "not" should be "note" in my above comment. Sorry for this typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overdoing with color packages. Pass the options through the beamer options:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|a|b|a|b|a|b|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{LightCyan}
  Name & Name&Name&NameName&NameName\\
  \hline
  \color{RubineRed}{NameName}&-&-&-&-\\
  NameName&NameName B &NameName B &- &NameName B\\
  NameName&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A\\
  NameName&NameName B &NameName &-&- \\
  NameName&NameName C&NameName C&NameName C&-\\
  NameName&-&NameName&-&-\\
  NameName&-&NameName&-&\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
} % end of scope of "\resizebox"  directive
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For instance, if I change   `\rowcolor{LightCyan}`to`\rowcolor{\color{RubineRed}} `an error appears 'undeclared color  doesn't match its definition`.I would like to know if there is a way to use ` dvipsnames` for `\rowcolor`

Comment: Don't use \color inside \rowcolor. Only `\rowcolor{RubineRed}` should work.

Comment: Is there a way to display the first row distinct from the rest of the rows?For instance, setting a different font type for the first row /first column.

Comment: Don't extend questions in comments like this. Create a new question.